# Let $V$ be a finite dimensional linear space and let $S$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove that a basis for $V$ need not contain a basis for $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional linear space and let $S$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove that every basis of $S$ is part of a basis for $V$ but a basis for $V$ need not contain a basis for $S$.

**Attempt:**

For any finite vector space $Z$, let $B_Z$ denote the set of basis elements for $Z$.

Let $B_V= \{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n\}$ and $B_s=\{s_1,s_2.\cdots,s_k\}$

where $\dim V = n, \dim S = k$

**$(i)$ Every basis of $S$ is part of a basis for $V$**

$B_s=\{s_1,s_2.\cdots,s_k\}$ can be extended to form a basis for $V$. Hence,  Every basis of $S$ is part of a basis for $V$.

But, I am unable to form an approach on how to prove that basis for $V$ need not contain a basis for $S~~$.

**(I started with : Let us assume that every basis of $V$ contains a basis for $S$)**

Could anyone please give me a direction to proceed ahead.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Surely there is at least one element in $V$ which is not in $S$...

Comment: @anon how can I prove this.

Comment: Sorry I had the letters mixed around, and you need to assume $S$ is a *proper* subspace. Now try thinking about it for more than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

You just need a counterexample. I would look at $V=\mathbb R^2$, and the standard basis, then you just need to find a subspace that doesn't contain any of the vectors of the standard basis.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract $2^n$ subsets from a basis with $n$ elements. So you can generate at most $2^n$ subspaces.

In the case of real or complex spaces, a space of dimension $n>1$ has infinitely many subspaces.

But it's easier to consider the basis $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ and finding a nonzero subspace that doesn't even contain those vectors.